# Toggling Between a CSS class with pure javascript on 'n' elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, classiejs

Working on creating functionality where when the user clicks on one of the products (each of the elements have the same assigned ID `card-reveal`) it adds a `CSS class` to the container specifically clicked (active state) to show information for that specific item and then finally, when the user clicks the cancel button the CSS class is removed (activate state gone).

Unfortunately I have run to a few hiccups where when I click on the 1st element it adds the class to that element but the other elements I click do not add the class, as well the close button does not function at all. I would like to finish the solution in **Pure Javascript**. Also if you see a few classie() methods, I am using [Classie.js](https://github.com/desandro/classie) to help with CSS class toggling.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank You!

**Html**

```
<a  id="card-reveal" class="card-view" href="javascript:void(0)"><h3 class='hover-title'>View More</h3></a>
<div class="card-cover">
                            <span class="card-exit"></span>

                            <a class="card-follow" href="javascript:void(0)">Follow {{object.product_website_name}}.com</a>
                            <a class="card-buy" target="_blank" href="{{object.product_slug_url}}">Buy {{object.product_name }}</a>
                            <a id="card-close" class="card-info" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="icon-indie_web-03"></span></a>
                            <ul class="card-social">
                                <label>Share</label>
                                <li><a href="#"><span  class="icon-indie_web-04"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span  class="icon-indie_web-05"></span></a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card-cover {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(255, 91, 36, 0.9);
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index:200;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 400px, 0);
    transform:translate3d(0, 400px, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     -webkit-transition-property:opacity, transform;
    transition-property:opacity, transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
    transition-duration:0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);   
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}


 .card-cover.card--active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform:translate3d(0, 0px, 0);   
}
```

**JS below:**

```
var cardContainer = document.querySelector('.card-cover'),
                cardTargets = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#card-reveal' ) ),
                eventType =  mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
                cardClose = document.getElementById('card-close'),
                resetMenu = function() {
                    classie.remove( cardContainer, 'card--active' );
                },
                resetMenuClick = function( ) {
                    cardCloseaddEventListener(globalMenuEventType, function() {
                        resetMenu();
                        document.removeEventListener(eventType, resetMenuClick);
                    }, false);      
                };

            cardTargets.forEach(function (element, index) {


                if( element.target ) {
                    element.addEventListener(eventType, function( event ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();

                        classie.add(cardContainer, 'card--active');

                        document.addEventListener(eventType, resetMenuClick);
                    } ,false);
                }

            });
```

Comment: What is this "classie" thing?

Comment: @Pointy using Classie.js https://github.com/desandro/classie

Comment: "*[Each] of the elements have the same assigned ID...*" - so why are you using invalid HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas the id is begin repeated due to the fact I am using django and each <a> in the for loop is getting repeated with unique content to each but with the same target ID.

Comment: Then you need to fix that problem; an `id` ***must be unique within the document,*** it's not optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two simple ways I can think of doing something like this.

First, if you can't designate ID's for each card (which it sounds like you can't), you're going to have to go by class names. Like it was mentioned in the comments, you really don't want to use the same ID for multiple elements.

Part of the reason for this is, as you can see from my examples below, that the .getElementById() method is only meant to return one element, where the other methods like .getElementsByClassName() will return an array of elements.

The problem we're trying to solve is that the sub-content you want to display/hide has to be attached to the element you click somehow. Since we're not using ID's and you can't really rely on class names to be unique between elements, I'm putting the div with the information inside a container with the element that toggles it.

Inside a container div, are two divs for content. One is the main content that's always visible, the other is the sub-content that only becomes visible if the main content is clicked (and becomes invisible when clicked again).

The benefit of this method is that since there are no ID's to worry about, you can copy/paste the cards and they'll each show the same behaviour.

```js
var maincontent = document.getElementsByClassName("main-content");
// Note: getElemenstByClassName will return an array of elements (even if there's only one).

for (var i = 0; i < maincontent.length; i++) {
  //For each element in the maincontent array, add an onclick event.
  maincontent[i].onclick = function(event) {

    //What this does is gets the first item, from an array of elements that have the class 'sub-content', from the parent node of the element that was clicked:
    var info = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub-content")[0];

    if (info.className.indexOf("show") > -1) { // If the 'sub-content' also contains the class 'show', remove the class.
      info.className = info.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)show(?!\S)/g, '');
    } else { // Otherwise add the class.
      info.className = info.className + " show";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.main-content {
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-content {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
.show {
  /* The class to toggle */
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Here is the main content that's always visible.</div>
  <div class="sub-content">Here is the sub content that's only visible when the main content is clicked.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Here is the main content that's always visible.</div>
  <div class="sub-content">Here is the sub content that's only visible when the main content is clicked.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Here is the main content that's always visible.</div>
  <div class="sub-content">Here is the sub content that's only visible when the main content is clicked.</div>
</div>
```

The second method, would be to use one div for the content that you want to show/hide, and clicking on an element will toggle both its visibility and it's content.

I'll use the previous example as a base, but ideally you would have some kind of MVVM framework like react, knockout, or angular to help you with filling in the content. For the sake of this example, I'm just going to use the text from the div of sub-content.

```js
var info = document.getElementById("Info");
var maincontent = document.getElementsByClassName("main-content");

for (var i = 0; i < maincontent.length; i++) { //getElemenstByClassName will return an array of elements (even if there's only one).
  maincontent[i].onclick = function(event) { //For each element in the maincontent array, add an onclick event. 

    //This does the same as before, but I'm getting the text to insert into the info card.
    var text = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("sub-content")[0].innerHTML;
    info.innerHTML = text; // Set the text of the info card.

    info.style.display = "block"; //Make the info card visible.
  }
}

info.onclick = function(event) {
  info.style.display = "none"; // If the info card is ever clicked, hide it.
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.main-content {
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-content {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px;
}
#Info {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Info" class="container">Here is some test information.</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Link 1.</div>
  <div class="sub-content">You clicked link 1.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Link 2.</div>
  <div class="sub-content">You clicked link 2.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Link 3.</div>
  <div class="sub-content">You clicked link 3.</div>
</div>
```